# Collecting AJAX generated text box values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-table

My script’s AJAX calls the following PHP file and prints a table with `$attrib` and text boxes.

Can somebody tell me how to collect the `$attrib` and text box in an array or something like that?

Code tried is giving values like `"assetattrib%5B%5D=model"`. So please help me to correct this or show me a new way to do the same.

```
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='12' cellpadding='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' width='700' id=addattrib >";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  $attrib = $row['attrib'];
  echo "<tr bgcolor='white'>
    <td class='value'>$attrib</td>
    <td class='value'><input type=text name=assetattrib[] value = '' </td>
  </tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type=submit name='btnSaveAsset' id = 'btnSaveAsset' value='Save' >";
```

I tried the code below.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSaveAsset", function() {
  $(document.getElementsByName('assetattrib[]')).each(function() {
    var x = $(this).serialize();
    alert(x);
  });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as there might be an easier/better way of formatting your html to retrieve the info that you want.

Comment: what I need is display form based on the type of device being added. for example, 10 elements displayed when inserting the device A and 15 for device B. these(10 or 15 elements) attributes are stored in mysql database.

Comment: Just noticed that there isn't a closing bracket for your input statement. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: Not that jeff. i just corrected it.

Comment: Are you really echoing this? `echo "<input type=submit name=btnSaveAsset id = btnSaveAsset value=Save >";` You missed every quote wrapping attribute values..

Comment: I am echoing it to submit the new form. It's working fine.  just added the quotes.

Comment: `It's working fine` means problem solved, or that is was working anyway? (BTW, still missing the quotes around the value)

Comment: What is your expected ending? What do you need in your *array*? Can you provide a jsfiddle with static html to work on?

Comment: @Joaquin 0, button is working fine. problem still there. At the end I should get $attribute -> value pair in a array. I will create a jsfiddle.

Comment: created the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/user1000/sy0wx8gb/   .$(document).on("click", is used as the form is generated as a result of a ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## IMPORTANT:

PHP `mysql_` extension is **deprecated** and using it represents a major security issue. According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

---

### Now the actual answer:

I suggest some changes in your HTML, if you can make them:

- Wrap the table where the `<input>`s are into a `<form>` element
- Give the generated `<input>`s the `name` attribute given by `$attrib`, for example `<input name="user" />`

**If you cannot modify the PHP/HTML code let me know and we'll find a workaround**

I updated your jsfiddle using this changes. Your PHP code should end up like this:

```
<form id="btnSaveAsset" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table border='1' cellspacing='12' cellpadding='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' width='700' id='addattrib'>

        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                $attrib = $row['attrib']; ?>

                <tr bgcolor='white'>
                    <td class='value'><?php echo $attrib; ?></td>
                    <td class='value'><input type='text' name='<?php echo $attrib; ?>' /> </td>
                </tr>

        <?php } ?>

    </table>
    <input type=submit name='btnSaveAsset' id='btnSaveAsset' value='Save' />
</form>
```

Then, you collect your data with one of this options:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSaveAsset", function () {

    var data = $("#myForm").serializeArray();
    console.log(data); // Array of objects

});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSaveAsset2", function () {

    var tempData = $("#myForm").serializeArray();
    var data = {};

    $.each(tempData, function () {
        data[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    console.log(data); // Just an object

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/sy0wx8gb/1/
Check your JS console (Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and go to `Console` tab) to see the results.

Comment: Thanks, It is working. Really appreciate. I am determined to go in a good learning curve.